# Babel doesn't cover append method?

Tags: internet-explorer, append, babeljs, appendchild, polyfills

new to Babel and it's working great mostly but I am confused about why Babel does not cover the append method. Heres my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "> 1%"
          ]
        },
        "useBuiltIns": false,
        "debug": true,
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "dist/**",
    "lib/*.min.js",
    "productionJS/*.js"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes"
  ]
}
```

I tried using useBuildIns = "entry" and "usage" but it didn't make a difference. Do I need to add more plugins or set a different presets to cover append as well?

Currently, my workaround is using the polyfill from the link below
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

any tips will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`babel` converts modern JavaScript syntax into backwards compatible code for older browsers. `append` is a DOM method, use a polyfill per MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)